# Find the duration of runtime using date for a certain column using SQL

Tags: sql

I have the below table:

[image]

I want to find out the duration of each 'Tag_ID'.

Example **Tag_ID 29558** has 7 entries, and i want to find out the cumulative duration taken for it to execute **11:51 - 11:45 = 6 mins.**
Similarly for **Tag_ID 36326 the duration is 11:58 - 11:52 = 6 mins.**

The first column 'ID'  needs to be ignored and not considered.

How to group by all these Tag_Id together and find out the duration of these Tag_id using SQL statement.

I tried the below code, and it didnt work:

```
   SELECT * FROM silver_hemmelrathmofa_skynet.dbo_mofa1_perlmuehle_data
   group by Perlmuehle_Auftrag
```

Getting this error:
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: expression 'spark_catalog.silver_hemmelrathmofa_skynet.dbo_mofa1_perlmuehle_data.`Id`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Sure, thanks will keep in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to subtract the maximum `datetime` from the minimum.  You can calculate them:

```
select d.tag_id, max(datetime), min(datetime)
from silver_hemmelrathmofa_skynet.dbo_mofa1_perlmuehle_data d
group by d.tag_id;
```

How you calculate the difference depends on the database you are using.  In some, it is as simple as:

```
max(datetime) - min(datetime)
```

However, date/time functions are notoriously database-dependent, so this needs to be modified for your specific engine.